# variables between if, else conditon

Tags: php

i want to use a variable between two blocks of if/else condition.

```
if(isset($_GET['aaa']))
{
  code to be executed;
  $example='a string or codes(calculating)';
}
else  //if(isset($_GET['bbb']))
{
  code to be executed;
}
```

how can i use $example in else clause? explain that for example at the first time the if clause is true and $example is calculated and for the second loading, else is true and now i want to use $example. i declare $example as static variable but it doesn't work.
thanks for your help :)

Comment: What is your question? Do you assume that the variable is available in a different request or this this code wrapped in a function that is called multiple times? To use $example in the else clause you have to define it outside of the if-construct and initialize it with a default value. If you want the variable to persist between request, use some other method like session, database etc...

Comment: With second loading, do you mean a page reload / refresh, or do you mean this code is part of a function which is called twice in your php script?

Comment: @Francodi i mean a page reload

Comment: @Rangad it's not from a function. this if/else clause is just in the middle of a page

Comment: Ok so I undeleted my answer (please have a look at it below) as I did not missunderstand you - a session is a way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a session variable for this:

Add a

```
session_start();
```

on the very beginning of your PHP script.

Your code could look like this then:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['example'])
{   
    $_SESSION['example'] = some default value;
}

if(isset($_GET['aaa']))
{
  code to be executed;
  $_SESSION['example'] ='a string or codes(calculating)';
}
else
{
  code to be executed;
  use $_SESSION['example'] here
}
```

The `$_SESSION['example']` can get a value everywhere you want and you can read it after page refreshes as well.

If you need more samples and explanations about $_SESSION, you can check out this site: http://www.php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.session.php

Answer (score 0):

Best way to use `$example` in both conditions is to declare it before `if`:

```
$example = '';

if(isset($_GET['aaa']))
{
  code to be executed;
  $example='a string or codes(calculating)';
}
else
{
  //other stuff using $example
  $example = 'foo';
}
```

Reading [this article](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) might become very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

in your case try **SESSIONS**..

```
if(isset($_GET['aaa']))
{
  code to be executed;
  $_SESSIONS['example']='a string or codes(calculating)';
}
else
{
  //other stuff using $_SESSIONS['example']
     $_SESSIONS['example'] = 'foo';
}
```

or you may want to initialize $_SESSIONS['example'] even before **if block** with some default value